# How can I disable a component once a raycast is no longer on an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a raycast that enables an outline component if the object has one, but I want it to be that when the raycast is no longer on that object the component is disabled. I keep on getting errors with my attempted solutions. Here is my code, the stuff about the text is not realated to my problem:

```
private void ShootRaycast()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out hit, viewRange))
        {
            if (hit.transform.name == "Player")
            {
                objectText.text = "Object: Ground";
            }
            else
            {
                objectText.text = "Object: " + hit.transform.name;
            }

            if (hit.transform.GetComponent<Outline>())
            {
                hit.transform.GetComponent<Outline>().enabled = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objectText.text = "Object: None";
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are calling that method e.g
in `Update`.

You could simply keep a reference to the last hit object and disable it like e.g.

```
private Outline _currentOutline;

private void ShootRaycast()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out var hit, viewRange))
    {
        if (hit.transform.name.Equals("Player"))
        {
            objectText.text = "Object: Ground";
        }
        else
        {
            objectText.text = "Object: " + hit.transform.name;
        }

        // Note: Use TryGetComponent to avoid repeated usage of GetComponent
        if (hit.transform.TryGetComponent<Outline>(var outline))
        {
            // You are hitting a new object
            if(outline != _currentOutline)
            {
                // If you had enabled something else before, disable it first
                if(_curtentOutline) 
                {
                    _currentOutline.enabled = false;
                }

                // Enable and store the current hit outline
                outline.enabled = true;
                _currentOutline = outline;
            }
        }
        // Hitting something that has no outline component
        else
        {
            // if there was a current outline
            if(_currentOutline)
            {
                // Disable the current outline and forget the reference
                _currentOultine.enabled = false;
                _currentOutline = null;
            }
        }
    }
    // There is no hit at all
    else
    {
        objectText.text = "Object: None";

        // If there was a current outline
        if(_currentOutline)
        {
           // Disable it and forget the reference
            _currentOultine.enabled = false;
            _currentOutline = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great. I appreciate your comments explaining it as well.